# MySQL and Visual Studio not recognizing primary key

Tags: mysql, visual-studio, winforms

I've reduced this as basic as I can.  I'm getting the error: "dynamic sql generation for the update command is not supported against a selectcommand that does not return any key column information".

This would normally mean I don't have a primary key.  But I do and here is the create table for it (MySQL):

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable1` (
  `test_id` bigint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `test_label` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`test_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

MySQL and such are a fresh install of the latest stable release.  My Visual Studio is Community 2019.

I can add the Data Connection in Server Explorer just fine and I can see all two columns.  This is the only table in the testdb.  The above create statement comes from that connection in fact and it identifies that there is a primary key (test_id).  Looking at the column properties in Server Explorer shows the Column Key property having "PRI" in it.  Seems like it knows it's the primary key to me.

I go and add a new winform and only put a DataGridView on it.  From the Wizard on "Choose Data Source I select Add Project Data Source and pick database, dataset, select the connection string, pick all columns from the table, and click finish.

That's when I get the error.

Can't get much more basic than that.  What am I screwing up?  Is there some setting in MySQL or Visual Studio that's set wrong?  This is my first time trying MySQL and I'm not having any luck.

Gurr, Greg.
:)

Comment: I created the equivalent DB in MS SQL Mgmt Studio, connected to Server Explorer and then added to the DGV, this worked.  The MySQL DB still does not work.  The MSSQL variation shows a key symbol on the Test_ID field/column whereas the MySQL variation does not.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer of sorts.  The Unsigned in the MySQL definition was definitely causing the Connector or Visual Studio to choke.  Removing it from the column definition allowed it to work correctly.

I can live with a Signed BIGINT primary key column for my table.

-gg